# Retry connection related exceptions for MongoRepository CRUD operations

Tags: java, spring-boot, error-handling, repository, retry-logic

Basically we want to have a retry mechanism like @Retryable + @Recover for Database related actions. Exceptions related to connection to DB should be retried others exceptions are not. So i'm planning on just creating a wrapper for the repository to handle retry.

```
@Retryable(value = {DataAccessException.class}, maxAttempts = 1,
            backoff = @Backoff(delay = 60000))
public Entity save(Entity entity) {
    return repository.save(entity);
}
```

Now I'm not even sure if DataAccessException is actually thrown by MongoRepository and I don't think it's exclusively about connection problems. How can I be sure I got all the exceptions about connection retried?